# How to disable tools mockup data in preview?

Tags: android-studio

In android studio, when working with xml layouts. You can optionally specify `tools:...` in order to provide mockup data that will be seen in the sidebar preview tab.

Is there anyway to disable this? (e.g. toggle between `tools` visibility) in the preview?